# Get sum over a column value that is determined by two other column values in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table `MY_TABLE`

```
ID | SEQ | TYPE | VAL
1  | 2   | A    | 100
1  | 3   | A    | 100
1  | 2   | B    | 200
1  | 3   | A    | 100
1  | 3   | B    | 200
2  | 25  | X    | 100
2  | 24  | Y    | 200
2  | 24  | X    | 300
2  | 25  | Y    | 400
2  | 25  | X    | 50
```

Here in `MY_TABLE`, each `ID` has a set of `Seq` values and `Type` values. I want to get the sum of `VAL` rows per `TYPE` that belong to each `ID`s `max(Seq)`.

Expected output:

```
ID| SEQ | TYPE | SUM(VAL)
1 | 3   | A    | 200  <- 100 + 100
1 | 3   | B    | 200  
2 | 25  | X    | 150  <- 100 + 50
2 | 25  | Y    | 400
```

What I tried:

```
-- this sub query finds the max(seq) for each ID
with max_seq as (
  select id, max(seq) max_seq
  from my_table t
  group by id)
-- select query on my_table
select
  bd.id,
  bd.seq,
  bd.type,
  sum(bd.val)
from my_table bd
-- joining on id-max_seq pair
inner join max_seq 
  on 
  (max_seq.id = bd.id)
  and
  (max_seq.max_seq = bd.seq)
-- sum(val) per ID, MAX(SEQ), TYPE
group by bd.id, bd.seq, bd.type;
```

**Question:**

The above query works well for smaller tables but gets slower when the table is bigger. Is there an efficient way of getting this output? (Maybe without using two joins on the same table with a sub query?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid the self-join by using a subquery which gets a ranking for each row based on the `id` and `seq`:

```
select id, seq, type, sum(val)
from (
  select id, seq, type, val, rank() over (partition by id order by seq desc) as rnk
  from my_table
)
where rnk = 1
group by id, seq, type
order by id, seq, type;

        ID        SEQ T   SUM(VAL)
---------- ---------- - ----------
         1          3 A        200
         1          3 B        200
         2         25 X        150
         2         25 Y        400
```

Because of the `order by seq desc`, the `rnk` value is 1 for the highest `seq` for each `id`. The outer query then just filters on `rnk = 1`, limiting the output and the aggregation to those lowest-rank (highest-`seq`) rows.

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=43c9301276dbfffefffae51307bd2143)

Comment: Thanks! I'd check this. BTW, is there a tool that we can compare timings of oracle queries beforehand?

Comment: @akilat90 - you can look at the [execution plans](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/tgsql/query-execution-plans.html) to spot potential bottlenecks before running the actual query. Not exactly what you're asking for but useful nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks! I will accept this answer after a time comparison on my table. It will take a bit of time.